# How C bit fileds get merged?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I haven't coded in C for long.
For the below code:

```
struct {
    int a :1;
    int b :1;
    int c :1;
} test1;
```

For test1, since each field only needs 1 bit, so 1 byte (8 bits) should be enough for test1.

But the `sizeof(test1)` returns 4 with GCC returns 4. Why?

### Add 1

```
struct {
    char a :4;
    short b :3;
} test2;
```

For test2, since `char` is 8 bits > 4 + 3, so I think 1 byte is enough for test2.
But still `sizeof(test2)` returns 4 with GCC.

How could `sizeof(test2)` return 4? A `char` + a `short` = 3 bytes at most.

Comment: Don't use signed integers for singe bits. Unless you are aware they can only represent `0` and **`-1`** for most implementations.

Answer (score 4):

You declared those fields as part of `int`, so you've done the same as

```
struct {
    int x;
} test1;
```

which is as big as an `int` (usually 4, but depends on the architecture).

Try:

```
struct {
   unsigned char a :1;
   unsigned char b :1;
   unsigned char c :1;
}
```

The second `struct` may need to deal with alignment, which again depends on architecture. This is not related to bitfields; you may reproduce with:

```
struct {
   char a;
   short b;
}
```

The compiler is adding padding, making it equivalent to

```
struct {
   char a;
   char invisible;
   short b;
}
```

This may be necessary in certain architectures, either for speed or because the architecture does not allow unaligned access.

Comment: Thanks. Your char sample returns 1 as expected. And I updated my question.

Comment: Your second question is different, please don't bait-and-switch :)

Comment: sorry for that. Your answer is at warp speed. :)

Comment: There is no guiarantee the `struct` will only occupy a single byte. There still can be requirements for padding/alignment which result in a larger size. And using `char` for bitfields is even worse tha `int`, as its signed-ness is implementation defined, so on one platform `char a:1` can yield `0`, `1`, on another `0` and `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you've strayed outside of the C spec:

C112 6.7.2.1:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified
>   version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other
>   implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether
>   atomic types are permitted.

Using shorts and chars and such for bitfields are up to the compiler.

However, GCC is nice about it. According to the GCC docs:

> - 'Allowable bit-field types other than '_Bool', 'signed int', and
>      'unsigned int' (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).'
>
>   Other integer types, such as 'long int', and enumerated types are
>      permitted even in strictly conforming mode.

About your questionss:

> For test1, since each field only needs 1 bit, so 1 byte (8 bits)
>   should be enough for test1.

Implementation dependent. GCC takes the ABI spec. I'm guessing you are on a x86 box from the offsets you see. From the GCC specs:

> - 'The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (C90
>     6.5.2.1,
>      C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).'
>
>   Determined by ABI.

The [x86 Linux ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) section 3.5 will describe what you are seeing in your sample program on a 32-bit linux box. For an x86_64 bitfields change quite a bit. See the [AMD64 architecture supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) section 3.1.2.

> But the sizeof(test1) returns 4 with GCC and sizeof(test2) returns 4. 
>   Why?

i386 ABI figure 3.9 may shed some light:

[image]

> How could sizeof(test2) return 4? A char + a short = 3 bytes at most.

These are both as specified in the i386 ABI. About padding, it says:

> Aggregates (structures and arrays) and unions assume the alignment of
>   their most strictly aligned component. The size of any object,
>   including aggregates and unions, is always a multiple of the object’s
>   alignment. An array uses the same alignment as its elements. Structure
>   and union objects can require padding to meet size and alignment
>   constraints.

Just for an example, gcc 5.4 (x86_64) does something quite different from what you are seeing on your version:

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>
struct {char a:1, b:2, c:3;} test1;
struct {char a: 1; short b: 2; char c:3;} test2;
struct {int a:1, b:2, c:3;} test3;
int main(){
    printf("t1 %ld t2 %ld t3 %ld \n",
       sizeof(test1), sizeof(test2),
       sizeof(test3));
    return 0;
}
$ ./foo 
t1 1 t2 2 t3 4
```

Structures are no longer padded to 4 byte boundaries, so test1 is now just a single byte.  Somehow, even though I can't find it in the x86_64 ABI, gcc is merging bitfields in test2 so the total structure is only 2 bytes. It seems like a bug to me because the x86_64 ABI (pg 13) says:

> - bit-fields are allocated from right to left
> - bit-fields must be contained in a storage unit appropriate for its 
>     declared type

Maybe a language lawyer can figure out how you can read these to allow merging of the bitfields in test2. I would have guessed 4 bytes for the {char, short, char}.